# Creating clojure add function using recursion

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm trying to wrap my head around recursion with clojure. I'm getting a stack overflow error with the following code, can anyone spot the issue?

(I know this is inefficient but it's strictly for learning purposes)

```
user=> (defn addall
         ([] 0)
         ([& x]
           (if (empty? x) 0)
           (+ (first x) (addall (rest x)))))
user/addall
user=> (addall 1)
StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.ArraySeq.next (ArraySeq.java:78)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your parenthesization is wrong -- your `if` needs an `else` form.  I suspect you meant something like:

```
(defn addall
  ([] 0)
  ([& x]
     (if (empty? x) 
         0   ;;; <=== no ')' after 0
         (+ (first x) (addall (rest x))))))  ;;; <== extra ')' here
```

But even with that fixed, your code is still wrong:  it assumes that it's called with multiple arguments -- `(addall 1 2 3)` -- but recurs by passing itself a list -- `(addall [2 3])`.  This results in it getting stuck in a loop that doesn't make any progress, which you can observe by adding a `print` statement:

```
(defn addall
  ([] 0)
  ([& x]
     (print (str "new x: " x "\n"))
     (if (empty? x) 
         0   ;;; <=== no ')' after 0
         (+ (first x) (addall (rest x))))))
```

This actually produced a segfault on my computer!

Also, it has two base cases.  I'd suggest this instead:

```
(defn addall
  [xs]
  (if (empty? xs) 
      0
      (+ (first xs) 
         (addall (rest xs)))))
```

To be called with a vector:

```
(addall [1 2 3])
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a variadic function, you'd also need `apply`:

```
(defn addall
  [& x]
  (print (str "new x: " x "\n"))
  (if (empty? x) 
      0
      (+ (first x) 
         (apply addall (rest x))))) ;;; <=== apply addall
```

---

That said, you should note that Clojure does not have tail-call optimization, which means that this code would fail with medium-sized inputs.  Clojure encourages the use of `loop/recur` and built-in sequence processing functions instead.

Comment: But this isn't causing the stack overflow. The first call `x` is bound to `(1)`, the second and subsequent it is bound to `(())`, which is not empty. An option would be `(apply addall (rest x))`.

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense, would you know how I would go about this using & in theory? How would I break down the arguments in a recursive fashion?

Comment: @LinuxN00b good question -- I've edited that in to my answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
(defn addall ([x] (if (empty? x) 0 (+ (first x) (addall (rest x))))))
```

as mentioned by Matt Fenwick, you should use loop/recur. A more idiomatic approach is to use reduce:

```
(reduce + [1 2 3 4 5])
```

There is a lot of wonderful tools baked in to clojure, and often you don't need things like loop/recur or explicit recursion.

Comment: I'm still getting the stack overflow error with your code when I add the & operator. I know reduce would be the smart way to do this, however I'm trying to understand how to properly create a recursive function from scratch in order to fully understand it